# React collapse not working after navbar set to fixed

Tags: reactjs, position, navbar, react-bootstrap

In my react app, using React-Bootstrap, I set the navbar to fixed after srcolling, but after that I'm unable to use the toggler button, that was working before scrolling :

```
const [sticky, setSticky] = useState('');
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
  }, []);
const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      // window height changed for the demo
      windowHeight > 150 ? setSticky('top') : setSticky('');
    }
  };

 return (
    <Navbar bg="light" fixed={stickyClass} className="menu">
       <Container fluid >
            
       </Container>
    </Navbar>
     <Collapse in={open} timeout={200}>
      <Container fluid className="dropdown-container">
        <Row className="dropdown">
        
        </Row>
      </Container>
     </Collapse>
    )
```

CSS

```
.menu {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 7rem;
   border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); 
}
.dropdown-container {
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I created for the useState, useEffect and stickNavbar corresponding items:

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
  }, []);
const scrollPos = () => {
if (window !== undefined) {
  let posHeight = window.scrollY;
  setScroll(posHeight) 
}
```

};

than I used them to follow the change in the scroll Y coordinates to set the distance of the  position + rem in pixels of the height of the navbar:

```
<Container fluid className="dropdown-container" style= 
  {{top:`${112+scroll}`+"px"}}>
```